# Stop Helmet Content Security Policy from directing https

Tags: javascript, node.js, content-security-policy, helmet.js

I am new to using the Helmet library for adding layers of security to my Node app, but noticed that when I was deploying my app on my server that I ran into issues when I configured the content security policy. As a result it's not loading needed javascript and css files as it's looking for the files on https while currently the server is using http.

What I would like to do is to be able to change the default from "https" to "http" when working on my development server, is there a way to change this in the configuration. I tried setting the maxAge property to "0" but that did not work either. The only way I have been able to get this to work is by removing the CSP entirely which i would rather not do.

Here is my helmet configuration code:

```
const scriptSrcUrls = [
    "https://polyfill.io",
    "https://maps.googleapis.com",
    "https://kit.fontawesome.com",
    "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net",
];
const styleSrcUrls = [
    "https://kit-free.fontawesome.com",
    "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net",
    "https://maps.googleapis.com",
    "https://fonts.googleapis.com",
    "https://use.fontawesome.com",
    "https://polyfill.io"
];
const connectSrcUrls = [
    "https://polyfill.io",
    "https://maps.googleapis.com",
];
const fontSrcUrls = [
    "https://fonts.gstatic.com"
];
app.use(
    helmet.contentSecurityPolicy({
        directives: {
            defaultSrc: [],
            connectSrc: ["'self'", ...connectSrcUrls],
            scriptSrc: ["'unsafe-inline'", "'unsafe-eval'", "'self'", ...scriptSrcUrls],
            styleSrc: ["'self'", "'unsafe-inline'", ...styleSrcUrls],
            workerSrc: ["'self'", "blob:"],
            childSrc: ["blob:"],
            objectSrc: [],
            imgSrc: [
                "'self'",
                "blob:",
                "data:",
                "https://maps.gstatic.com",
                "https://maps.googleapis.com",
                "https://images.unsplash.com",
            ],
            fontSrc: ["'self'", ...fontSrcUrls],
        },
    })
);
```

Comment: Helmet maintainer here. You should be able to use `https:` URLs in any environment. You could also change your `scriptSrcUrl`s with an `if` statement if that works for you. Helmet doesn't have anything like this built in, though.

Comment: Hi Evan - just to clarify, I want to use http, not https. Is it possible to configure helmet to use http and not https which seems to be the default?

Comment: No, but you can choose to change the arguments you pass in. For example, `if (production) { scriptSrcUrls = ['https://...'] } else { scriptSrcUrls = ['http:/'] }`.

Answer (score 1):

When you can not access your server under `localhost` but run it locally without SSL (using `http` instead of `https`), then you can set the `contentSecurityPolicy` attribute in the *helmet* configuration to `false` - e.g. like this:

```
app.use(helmet({
    // Disable https preference for development:
    contentSecurityPolicy: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? false : {
        directives: {
            'script-src': ['\'self\''],
            'img-src': ['\'self\'', 'data:'],
            'connect-src': ['\'self\'']
        }
    },
    [...]
}));
```

This way, no SSL is expected by your browser for loading external resources.